# Cannot enable mb_string in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, mbstring

I need to use `mb_strlen` to sort an array of words with diacritics, but PHP does not recognize this function, although `mb_string` is installed.

So, if I say

```
function sortByStrlen($a, $b)
{
  if (mb_strlen($a, "utf-8") === mb_strlen($b, "utf-8")) {
    return $a > $b;
  } else {
    return mb_strlen($b, "utf-8") - mb_strlen($a, "utf-8");
  }
}

#sort my array
usort($myArray, 'sortByStrlen');
```

Won't work on my Ubuntu virtual machine that is running on the server, although it was working on my Windows local machine,

I've spent over 2,5 hours searching this issue and I've tried many solutions, both here in StackOverflow and in AskUbuntu.

These solutions did not work for me:

[PHP: Call to undefined function mb_strlen() - on custom compiled PHP with mbstring enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203730/php-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen-on-custom-compiled-php-with-mbstri)

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419102/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen)

[Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen() on PHP in Yii2 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940696/call-to-undefined-function-yii-helpers-mb-strlen-on-php-in-yii2-framework)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04

This is just to name a few! I did a deep search, but I did not find what I need. Please, do not mark it as duplicate because I really need help (indeed, this problem is making me tired).

I already installed mb_string through the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mbstring
```

I'm sure the `mbstring` module is compatible with my PHP version. Then, I uncommented the lines in php.ini to activate the `mbstring` module

```
;extension=mbstring
```

I also uncommented extensions:

```
extension_dir = "./"
```

I restarted the server:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I also see other modules, like `mysql`, when I use `php-m`.

When I run `phpinfo`, I can see that the `mbstring` is on the list of the modules being loaded.

If I run `php -m` on the terminal, it will give me a list of modules and `mbstring` is there.

HOWEVER, if I run:

```
<?php

var_dump(extension_loaded('mbstring'));
```

It will ouput:

```
bool(false)
```

Yet, after all of this, I restarted Apache and MySQL many times. So I can't see why `mbstring` is not being enabled!

As explained at the beginning of this post, I need to sort words with diacritics by their length. So, if you have another solution for this, I will accept it.

I'm not getting error messages because this is for production. The code is running on my personal website in a virtual machine; because it is production, PHP does not show errors by default and I don't know how to enable them.

**Notes:**
Ubuntu version is 18.04
PHP version is 7.3

**UPDATE  2**

As requested by @gview, if I run  `dpkg -l | grep php`, I get:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.3           7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-common                      2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3                 all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php-gettext                     1.0.12-0.1                                               all          transitional dummy package for php-php-gettext
ii  php-mbstring                    2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3             all          MBSTRING module for PHP [default]
ii  php-pear                        1:1.10.8+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all          PEAR Base System
ii  php-php-gettext                 1.0.12-0.1                                               all          read gettext MO files directly, without requiring anything other than PHP
ii  php-xml                         2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3             all          DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.3                          7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.3-cli                      7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.3-common                   7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.3-json                     7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.3-mbstring                 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.3-mysql                    7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.3-opcache                  7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.3-readline                 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        readline module for PHP
ii  php7.3-xml                      7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                     amd64        DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
```

That may help you help me.

Comment: .dll is windows libraries . i suggest you run `phpinfo();` to see which .ini file is correct and if it indeed tries to load mbstring

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually, I found `;extension=php_mbstring.dll` and `;extension=mbstring` . I uncommented both of them to make sure it would work

Comment: Try running `apt-get install php7.3-mbstring`. You *might* need to `sudo`.

Comment: More isn't better.  As previously advised, .dll is for windows only.  A .dll is a dynamic link library, which is a windows only technology.  Uncomment ONLY the php_mbstring entry and then report back whether or not you have mbstring showing up in the phpinfo().

Comment: I ran `apt-get install php7.3-mbstring` and it is up to date. Also, I commented again the lines `;extension=php_mbstring.dll `

Comment: Also as Catalyst stated, make sure you have the mbstring extension installed using the package manager for your version of php.  You might need to uninstall the generic version you installed.

Comment: Still, no results.

Comment: Please do a terminal `dpkg -l | grep php`  and update your question with the output.

Comment: @gview I used the command you said and I updated the question with the ouput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After over 3,5 hours of search, I found the solution!!! I HOPE IT WILL HELP SOMEONE ELSE !!

**THE ERROR**

So, the problem was that the `extension_dir` in the `php.ini` file was set to the wrong file. By default, it was to the following:

```
extension_dir = './'
```

**THE SOLUTION**

1. Open you terminal `ctrl+alt+t` and type:

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

In my case, it ouputs:

```
/user/lib/php/20180731
```

2. Find out your `php.ini` file:
   You can do that either by:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Or on the terminal

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

3. Go to your `php.ini` file and change the following line:

```
extension_dir = '/full/path/to/your/php/modules'
```

in my case, it was:

```
exension_dir = '/usr/lib/php/20180731'
```

**SEE MORE**

By the way, you have to do this after installing `mbstring`. To do that, You may find useful the following links:

[PHP: Call to undefined function mb_strlen() - on custom compiled PHP with mbstring enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203730/php-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen-on-custom-compiled-php-with-mbstri)

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419102/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mb-strlen)

[Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen() on PHP in Yii2 Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940696/call-to-undefined-function-yii-helpers-mb-strlen-on-php-in-yii2-framework)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04